# create directory (tree) phantomjs casperjs not working

Tags: directory, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm working on windows 10 X64

using casperjs and phantomjs

CasperJS version 1.1.2 at C:/casperjs, using phantomjs version 2.1.1

try to create multi dir with it but no luck, the only work is create 1 dir only

from document

http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/make-tree.html

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'D:\\test2\\2ss\\hhh\\gu';
if(fs.makeDirectory(path))
console.log('"'+path+'" was created.');
else
console.log('"'+path+'" is NOT created.');
phantom.exit();
```

result (path changed)

```
D:\work>casperjs dir.js
"D:\test\1\1\2" is NOT created.

D:\work>casperjs dir.js
"D:\test2" was created.  // this work when make 1 dir only

D:\work>casperjs dir.js
"D:\test3\2dd" is NOT created.

D:\work>casperjs dir.js
"D:\test2\2ss" was created. . // Working because test2 was created before

D:\work>casperjs dir.js
"D:\test2\2ss\hhh\gu" is NOT created.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change makedirectory to maketree. **It will work!**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'D:\\test2\\2ss\\hhh\\gu';
if(fs.makeTree(path))
console.log('"'+path+'" was created.');
else
console.log('"'+path+'" is NOT created.');
phantom.exit();
```

the result

```
D:\work>casperjs dir.js
"D:\test2\2ss\hhh\gu" was created.
```